# Why are std::begin() and std::end() overloaded for std::initializer_list in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

In C++11 (quoting N3337), `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are specified as (§24.7 [iterator.range]/p2-3)

> ```
> template <class C> auto begin(C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
> template <class C> auto begin(const C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
> ```
>
> 2 Returns: `c.begin()`.
>
> ```
> template <class C> auto end(C& c) -> decltype(c.end());
> template <class C> auto end(const C& c) -> decltype(c.end());
> ```
>
> 3 Returns: `c.end()`.

`std::initializer_list`, however, provides its own overloads for these functions (§18.9.3 [support.initlist.range]):

> ```
> template<class E> const E* begin(initializer_list<E> il) noexcept;
> ```
>
> 1 Returns: `il.begin()`.
>
> ```
> template<class E> const E* end(initializer_list<E> il) noexcept;
> ```
>
> 2 Returns: `il.end()`.

It seems that these overloads don't do anything beyond the base template, other than (1) having a `noexcept` specification and (2) taking their parameter by value. However, copying an `initializer_list` does nothing special (it just copies a pair of pointers or something equally lightweight), so (2) creates no difference in behavior. Moreover, the `begin()` and `end()` member functions of many standard containers are also `noexcept`, yet no overloads of `std::begin()`/`std::end()` are specified for those containers, so it seems unlikely the committee specified these overloads just for (1). Why, then, are these overloads provided?

Comment: It's also overloaded for `valarray`.

Comment: To me the obvious difference is the lack of return type inference. Was that introduced in a later revision maybe? Not sure.

Comment: @40two `valarray` doesn't have member `begin()` and `end()`, so the overloads are required for that.

Comment: Oh wait, the initializer lists are taken by **value**. Is that intentional?

Comment: @T.C. I know, I just mentioned for additional info.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't know. However, since copying an `initializer_list` does nothing special whatsoever, I don't think that's what led to the committee's decision to specify the extra overloads.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is explained in [N2930](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html), which proposed the change to add the overloads in question.
Emphasis mine:

> Summary of proposed changes
>
> - Specify range-based for statements without the use of concepts, using argument-dependent lookup of begin and end (which always includes those `begin` and `end` functions in namespace `std`) to provide the iterator to the beginning and ending of the sequence.
> - Specify range-based for statements **so that arrays and initializer lists have no dependencies on `<iterator>`.**
> - Refactor `<initializer_list>` so that it as no dependencies on other headers and includes no other headers.
> - Specify the library headers that are to `#include <initializer_list>`.

It seems like they didn't explain *why* they wanted `<initializer_list>` to have no dependency on `<iterator>`, but I think a reasonable guess is that the former is supposed to be available in a freestanding implementation whereas the latter might not be (Table 16, §17.6.1.3)

Comment: Hmm, I guess the question then is why they provided the extra overloads rather than adding `<initializer_list>` to the list of headers in §24.7 [iterator.range]/p1.

Comment: The way ranged-for looks for `begin`/`end` has changed since that proposal - it first looks for member functions, and as such has no need for those overloads anymore.